# Convert vb.net to vb6

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have written code in c# and vb.net but now the requirement is vb6.Can i convert vb.net code to vb6.How to add namespace in vb6 System.Security.Cryptography

Comment: Why would you want to do this on a first place?

Comment: Oh god why..  take your media and license for vb6 and burn it.. stamp on it before it's completely out and light it up again!

Comment: company requirement.they dont want .net framework.But i have use namespaces in vb.net as follows    Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO how can i add them to vb6.

Comment: Throw everything away, start from scratch.

Comment: Why do you keep saying as follows when nothing follows?

Comment: What operating system are they using, I expect you might find .Net already installed on Client Machines ... have you looked ?

Comment: Look into this, Visual Basic Fusion, where you can use .NET libraries in yoru VB6 code as long as the user has the .NET Framework installed. You basically make a COM Visible Wrapper around these .NET libraries that the VB6 app can talk to through the COM layer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364069(v=vs.80).aspx check it out.

Answer (score 9):

Quite apart from the fact that the language VB.NET is far more feature rich than VB6, the fact that you have developed in VB.NET means that you have made extensive use of the .NET class libraries (including System.Security.Cryptography that you give as an example). These are simply not available to VB6 code. There is no way to convert the code, you will have to start again.

If the company doesn't want the .NET Framework as you state, then you will have to either find some COM libraries that use the same functionality (that they are happy with you using), or you will have to roll your own (not advisable in the case of security functionality). Or you could find a different job...

Comment: +1. But before you actually quit your job, do sit down with the company and carefully explain to them that it would be much easier to use the .Net framework via COM interop, and ask them why it's not possible to use .Net.

Comment: COM interop doesn't really make sense here - if the OP can use .NET via COM interop, then the requirement to use VB6 has gone away anyway...

Comment: The requirement might be to implement some cryptography in an existing legacy VB6 application. In which case COM interop makes perfect sense. We don't know why the company has said "no .Net framework". In these situations it's important to make sure the decision-makers understand the consequences of the "no .Net framework" rule. Certainly I'd want to make my best effort to explain this before thinking about changing jobs. After all, to be an attractive candidate for the other jobs I need to have the skills to explain technical issues to non-technical decision makers

Comment: Why does COM interop make sense in an existing legacy VB6 application?  Interop is for incorporating COM into .Net, not the other way around.  Now, it seems to me that the question is pretty straightforward: the OP wants to know if he can use System.Security.Cryptography and System.IO in a VB6 application.  And all he gets is the standard trumpeting of WHY WHY WHY.  That's not helpful.  For the information of anyone who wishes to know, it's entirely possible to use SOME of the .Net framework in VB6.  And no, Mark, you don't use interop.  I'll explain on next post, as I haven't room otherwise.

Comment: Sunil, we'll take as an example System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed.  First, you have to find out where it is.  To do this, first open regedit.exe.  Open HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  Find System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed.  Open the CLSID folder there, and you'll see    A6673C32-3943-3BBB-B476-C09A0EC0BCD6.  Go to the CLSID folder, and look up this Clsid.  Open the folder, open the InprocServer32 folder, and you will see mscoree.dll.  Just add a reference in your VB6 program to mscoree.dll, and you'll be able to `dim MySHA as SHA512Managed` to your heart's content.

Comment: To expand on this a bit, look under System in the classes hive.  You'll find quite a few Cryptography classes, and a few IO classes as well.  Also, this assumes that you have the .Net framework installed.